# Marklogic how to retrieve text documents

Tags: marklogic

How can I return a list of text documents store in DB.  I use fn:document-uri() but return errors looking for node().  Thanks

```
13. let $uris := fn:document-uri(cts:search(fn:doc(),"sudo*","unfiltered"))
14. 
15. for $uri in $uris
```

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004)
>   fn:document-uri((fn:doc("/Howto-shutdown-and-restart-AWS-DEV.txt"),
>   fn:doc("/How-to-shutdown-restart-Oracle.txt"),
>   fn:doc("/How-to-shutdown-restart-MYSQL.txt"))) -- arg1 is not of type
>   node()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is complaining about the fact that you passed multiple nodes to a function that expects one.

You can either just add the function to the end of the path, so it iterates:

```
cts:search(doc(),"sudo*","unfiltered")/document-uri(.)
```

Or, since you just want the URIs from an unfiltered search, you're better off just using `cts:uris` directly:

```
cts:uris((),(),"sudo*")
```